# How to get members of a azure devops project project administrator group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

I have azure devops projects which contains a groups called "Project Administrators" . I am adding AAD members, AAD group to this Team Group.

Members added as type " aad user"
Group added as type "user"

Using Rest API "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com//_apis/GroupEntitlements//members"  I am able to retrieve all AAD members. But not AAD group. How Can I fetch AAD group?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case1

If you want to get **specific group** from your account, make use of below Rest API call:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups/{groupDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to know more in detail.

#### Case2

If you want **group entitlements of specific group** in your account, make use of below Rest API call:

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/groupentitlements/{groupId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/group-entitlements/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to know more in detail.

#### Case3

If you want to get **list of all groups** present in your current scope(account), make use of below Rest API call:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to know more in detail.

#### Case4

If you want to get **list of all group entitlements** in your account, make use of below Rest API call:

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/group-entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to know more in detail. Please find this [reference](https://michaelmaillot.github.io/tips/20210914-azdo-project-admin-members-programmatically/) if it is helpful.

Comment: In my scenario, I have a project A, having A1 as PA group. User B , User C , AAD group D are member of PA. How can I retrieve all 3 members of PA group ? Using GroupEntitlements/members , I am able to fetch only User B and User C. Not AAD group D

Comment: Hi @Snigdha, using [GroupEntitlements/members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), you can only fetch **direct** members of the group. In your case, AAD group D members are indirect (**transitive**) members. So, you can't fetch them.  Instead, you can fetch all users in current scope using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) !