# Azure DevOps Rest API - getting all members of AAD groups

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

In our Azure DevOps organization we have a lot of email aliases added as users. Those are AAD groups and some of them contain more AAD groups.
Now I'm looking into an option to get all users (people) that have access to a specific project in our Azure DevOps organization, but the best I can do is getting all direct users and all groups (regular Azure DevOps groups as well as AAD groups) and on top of that I can query direct members of an AAD group.

However, as soon as an AAD group has another email alias (AAD group) as a member, it seems I can't get that. I've seen no option in the API to accomplish this.

I've tried the following endpoints, but without luck:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#all-members-of-a-group (I only get AAD users, not groups within the group)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 (only direct members, too)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP (this seemed to be the most promising, but even with parameter queryMembership=expandDown it only gets direct members, but not groups that are direct members)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/group-entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP (didn't get members)

It looks like using the Microsoft Graph API would get this done, but I can't access that API. I only have access to the Azure DevOps Rest API.

Is there a way to either get all groups within an AAD group using the Azure DevOps Rest API or get all direct and indirect AAD group members?

Comment: Just adding: I think I've tried most of the endpoints that the [Azure DevOps Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) lists under "Graph", "Identities" and "Member Entitlement Management". Maybe there's some undocumented parameter for one of those endpoints or some other endpoint altogether that would allow getting indirect group members that I haven't discovered?!

Comment: I've also tried [Users - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) as suggested in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560750/how-to-get-members-of-a-azure-devops-project-project-administrator-group?rq=1. That lists all indirect members, but only from Azure DevOps groups (e.g. a DevOps team added as user to another team). But it doesn't list AAD groups added as members to teams.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could [list Group Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/group-entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) and then get the members of the AAD group use the [Get memmbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API.

Powershell Script like:

```
#Create a PAT in your organization
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "{PAT}"
$header = $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }
 
$organization = "{orgname}"

 
#get all groups.
$url = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header


#write-host $groups.value

$groups.value | ForEach-Object {
    #Write-Host "group" $_.id $_.group.origin
    if($_.group.origin -eq "aad"){
    Write-Host "group:" $_.group.displayName "groupid" $_.id 
    $url = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/GroupEntitlements/" + $_.id + "/members?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    #set retainedByRelease property to false
    $members = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    #write-host $members.members
    $members.members | ForEach-Object {
     write-host "user:" $_.user.mailaddress "userid:" $_.id 
     }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried that earlier, too. Actually, the Group Entitlements endpoint you've mentioned lists the groups where the account is a member, so I was using the [Groups - List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) endpoint that lists all groups for a specific scope. And the problem with the [Members - Get](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) endpoint: it lists "direct members of a Group", so no groups.

Comment: You could use the condition 'origin -eq "aad"' when listing the Groups, the response should be aad groups. And then you could get Members by using the AAD groups' ids.

Comment: Hello @GingYuan-MSFT your code didnt work for the AAD group, it didnt display me the members who are part of the aadgrp, any work around?

Comment: hello @ChrisO did you find any resolution for fetching the users of AAD group?